# interaction between parent and two children

Tags: angular

I have a component has three children
first step:
child1 is a reactive form to register users, once is submitted child2 has to be updated which is a list of users.

second step:
child2 has a list once clicks on a user child3 has to fetch details of child2 id to its reactive form to edit it.

how can I do that?

```
<!-- child 1 -->
<app-admission-add></app-admission-add>

<!-- child 2 -->
<app-admission-list (studentId)="updateId($event)"></app-admission-list>

<!-- child 3 -->
<app-admission-edit [studentId]="studentId"></app-admission-edit>
```

admission list ts

```
@Output() studentId = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public getStudentId(id: number){
    this.studentId.emit(id);
  }
```

admission edit ts

```
@Input() studentId: number;
this.getStudentById(this.studentId);
```

I tried to use shared service too but it is not updated at all, I want data synicing between these component once click or save.

```
export class SharedService {

  private studentListValue : number = 0;

  update(id: number) { 
    this.studentListValue = id;
  }

  get studentValue(){
    return this.studentListValue;
  }
}
```

on admission list html

```
<a (click)="sharedService.update(student.id)" />
```

advice please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent component does not detect any change in the sahred service, the `studentListValue`  should be defined as observable:

```
export class SharedService {

  private studentListValue : BehaviorSubject<number>

  update(id: number) { 
    this.studentListValue.next(id);
  }

  get studentValue(){
    return this.studentListValue.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then you need to subscribe:

```
<!-- child 3 -->
<app-admission-edit [studentId]="sharedService.studentValue | async"></app-admission-edit>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but, I got an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.studentListValue.next')` any advice? this happen when I click on one element of the list

Comment: this is the event `<a (click)="sharedService.update(student.id)" />`

Comment: try to initialize the subject:

`private studentListValue : BehaviorSubject<number> =  new BehaviorSubject<number>(1)`

Or provide more code to analyse even further